# Unix Timestamp in Clock

Tags: solana-program

If we have slot2>slot1, do we have necessarily unix_timestamp2>unix_timestamp1 ? I didn't found explicitly this information in the sysvar documentation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is guaranteed that time never goes backwards. You can see this point in the timestamp correction proposal at https://docs.solana.com/implemented-proposals/bank-timestamp-correction#timestamp-correction

> The Bank timestamp is corrected to this value if it is greater than or equal to the previous Bank's timestamp. That is, time should not ever go backward, so that locked up accounts may be released by the correction, but once released, accounts can never be relocked by a time correction.